# Motor constants and motor poles

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor

From what I read, if I'm dealing with a BLDC motor, the torque constant \$ K_t \$ and the back-EMF constant \$ K_e \$ are, numerically, the same (using SI units).

However, if the motor has a big number of pole pairs, do the constants still remain numerically equal? With a big number of pole pairs the mechanical speed is much slower than the electrical speed therefore changing \$ K_e \$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For an ideal motor* the relationship remains the same.  Big motor, little motor, 3 poles, 300 poles -- it's the same.

It's the same because of energy conservation: real motors don't store much energy so we say ideal motors don't store *any*.  The electrical power is \$v(t) i(t)\$, the mechanical power is \$T(t) \omega(t)\$, and for an ideal motor *they must equal*.  So you get \$v(t) i(t) = $T(t) \omega(t)\$, and from that you get
$$\frac{v(t)}{\omega(t)} = \frac{T(t)}{i(t)} \tag 1$$

For an ideal permanent-magnet DC motor \$\frac{T(t)}{i(t)}\$ is a constant, so you get \$k_T\$.

Note that I keep limiting the discussion to an ideal permanent-magnet motor -- there's various adjustments you need to make when the divergence from ideal gets bigger than your desired precision.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, when we add efficiency into the equation, it is not the same anymore, right?
The "various adjustments you need to make" start there?

Comment: Yes.  I didn't want to go there within this answer because it's not what you asked and I'm pretty sure the whole subject of motor modeling has been treated here before -- possibly by me.  If you can't find it, ask a separate question and you will get answers.

Comment: Thank you again